# How do I fix database permissions in Azure SQL Server as the owner and only user?

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql

I'm using cloud-based Azure SQL Server and SQL Database. To group tables within the db, I "successfully" created a new schema. However, all attempts to use the schema resulted in errors about not having permission, and I couldn't find a way to add the permission (see below). The trouble wasn't worth the troubleshooting, so I abandoned the idea and went back to my single existing schema name.

Since then, I can no longer create tables on my original schema, named qbo:

```
CREATE TABLE qbo.NewTable (
    pkey int PRIMARY KEY,
);

Started executing query at Line 1
Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The specified schema name "qbo" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
Total execution time: 00:00:00.034
```

I can create a table without a schema specified at all (which I assume is going to dbo), or with dbo specified, but then I can't query said table because the SELECT permission was denied.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewTable] (
    pkey int PRIMARY KEY,
);

Started executing query at Line 1
Commands completed successfully.
Total execution time: 00:00:00.194

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[NewTable]

Started executing query at Line 1
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'NewTable', database 'master', schema 'dbo'.
Total execution time: 00:00:00.036
```

When I try granting permissions:

```
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO <myUserName>

Started executing query at Line 1
Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
Total execution time: 00:00:00.035
```

I'm the only db user, and the server admin with the Owner role. I haven't found a way through the Portal to change anything, and any T-SQL statements in Azure Data Studio to attempt correcting everything result in the same type of error above. I'm assuming something in creating another schema changed some backend setting. But from what I can tell, I haven't specifically revoked any of the permissions I started with since creating the database, which has been running smoothly for about 3 months with CREATE, UPDATE, DROP, etc.

At a minimum, I need to go back to fully operating on my own db and qbo schema, but extra credit for helping me understand what I messed up and if I can actually use multiple schemas. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Based on your helpful comments and re-reading my own error messages, it finally clicked that I'm connected to different databases. I assumed at first that the db I created *was* the master db, so the comment didn't make sense. I don't know what the "master" db is yet (default?), but changing the Change Connection drop-down to my main db has cleared up most everything. Not sure how I changed it in the first place, but now I know to look there.

I'm still working on understanding the schemas, but at least I can get work done again.

Comment: Does `SELECT user;` return 'dbo'? That would explain the error on the `GRANT` but, as the database owner, you should have SELECT permissions on all tables.

Comment: `SELECT user` returns my username for the server admin login

Comment: What do you see as the owner when you view the database properties in SSMS or ADS? If it's not your user name, double check the server admin login database property in the portal.

Comment: Why are you creating objects in the `master` database anyway?

Comment: @DanGuzman: Database properties in ADS shows me as the owner

Comment: @Charlieface: basically, I don't know any better? My inability to answer your question or understand its implications shows I don't know what I'm doing. I've been an end-user for years, but am having to figure out setting up my own server/db from scratch with a new job. Fortunately I'm the only end user of my own db so far, but I'm just learning as I go. I'll try researching what you've brought up.

Comment: Just putting together some things from your comments. Adding update edit

Comment: Basically, the `master` database is the database which holds system information. It is the default, before you've created any other DBs, but you shouldn't really use it under normal circumstances. Once you create a DB, you can change your connection settings so that you automatically connect to that DB. Judging by your error message, you were still connected to `master`

Comment: @SteelReyn, I totally missed the master database in the error message. Short story, create a new user database for your user objects. You can do that from master with T-SQL [CREATE DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&preserve-view=true&tabs=sqlpool) statement of via the portal.

Comment: Hi @SteelReyn, could you please post your findings as an answer instead updating in the question. It would be helpful for the other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your helpful comments and re-reading my own error messages, it finally clicked that I'm connected to different databases. I assumed at first that the db I created was the master db, so the comment didn't make sense.

I have been working in my specifically created db up to this point without realizing there was a master db, and somehow in Azure Data Studio I was now connecting to the master. This is probably unrelated to my understanding of the schema creation; I just assumed they were related issues since they happened at the same time.

To fix, I changed the Change Connection drop-down to my main db. After that, I can create, update, drop, etc. again.

[image: Azure Data Studio - Change Connection drop-down]